# Ruby fixnum error

Tags: ruby

Please help me with this calculation code:

```
puts 'What is your first name?'
firstName = gets.chomp

puts 'What is your middlename?'
middleName = gets.chomp

puts 'What is your last name?'
lastName = gets.chomp

puts ' the number of characters in your name is ' + firstName.length + middleName.length + lastName.length
```

I am getting this error:

```
methods.rb:20:in `+': no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String (TypeError)
from methods.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

I tried using `to_i` method on `firstName`, `middleName`, and `lastName`, but it still throws the same error, so I believe the error is coming from the initial `puts`. I may however be wrong.

Comment: As with most programming languages, Ruby has a naming convention: modules and classes `LikeThis`, constants `LIKE_THIS`, symbols `:like_this`, variables, methods and procs `like_this`, (possibly prepended with `@, @@ or $`).  Have I forgotten anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to add a FixNum and a String. This is not possible.Ruby does not automagically convert Fixnums into Strings.

What you need to do is convert the FixNum into a string.
Here is a way you could write the above code such that it would work.

```
puts ' the number of characters in your name is ' + (firstName.length + middleName.length + lastName.length).to_s
```

or use interpolation which automatically calls the `to_s` method.

```
puts " the number of characters in your name is #{firstName.length + middleName.length + lastName.length}"
```

Comment: Brilliant! I Initially did this :

puts " the number of characters in your name is #{firstName.length} + #{middleName.length} + #{lastName.length}"

Comment: using #{} is best answer.

Comment: @ChangJuPark Do you have anything other than personal opinion which says the second is better?

Answer (score 1):

It's because `firstName.length` returns an `Integer`, and you can't add `Integer`s to `String`s.

You could just convert it to a `String`:

`firstName.length.to_s`

Comment: "you can't add Strings to Integers" => I think you meant "you can't add Integers to Strings".